# Edit bounding box around pixel art in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

At the moment, I am trying to resize the bounding box of the pixel art shown in the picture below. It is too big and I can't work with it like this. Is there any way to resize it in Illustrator without changing the dimensions of the graphic inside?

[image: This is the image]

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more? What is this graphic made out of? Did you use any masks?

Comment: You can't really change anythings bounding box without changing the actual content, no. Could you show us what exactly it is though (i.e. why is the bounding box so big; is it an imported image, masked etc.)?

Comment: It looks like an imported image, which would mean there isn't really anything you can do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is a pixel box around the image that is reflected in the size of the bounding box. Not know exactly what you goal is makes this answer somewhat random but here goes...I think you have three options: In illustrator put the image into a clipping mask and manipulate it from there OR open the image in photoshop and crop tight around your image. Or you could save it as a .png with a transparent background.

One more though. If you are in Illustrator CC you can use Isolation Mode. Hover your cursor over the box until it's outline is highlighted, then double click to direct select the box. The rest of the image should grey out so you know you are in IM. You can resize the bounding box as you like without affecting the image. Try this one first. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Judith, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. I merged your two posts, as we are a Q&A site, not a forum, and we're a bit precise about what goes where. If you have any questions, have a look at the help or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I'm trying to create a mask for plotter cutting and the bounding box makes my graphic very large. I've exported it to png and resized it in photoshop. I was wondering if it could be done in illustrator but in worked perfectly in photoshop. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to recrop the image too as close to the image as possible and it will reset the bounding box.